# Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

"Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page." this error appear when I added the script Manager to the password strength of AJAX toolkit.

i added the password strength beside the password field of my createuserwizard. 
why this error would appear when this is the only scriptmanager that i had in my website?

here is the code:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="20" />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate> 
 <asp:PasswordStrength ID="Password_PasswordStrength" runat="server" 
                                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Password"   DisplayPosition="RightSide"
                             StrengthIndicatorType="BarIndicator"
                              BarBorderCssClass="barBorder"
                               BarIndicatorCssClass="barInternal">
                         </asp:PasswordStrength>

                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                                ErrorMessage="Password is required." />   
      </ContentTemplate> </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Why is it called `ScriptManager2` if it's only one? :) Don't you have ToolkitScriptManager already? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1996095/55209

Comment: nope, it was actually ScriptManager1, i change it to ScriptManager2 to try whether the code will run. But end up, the same error appeared.

Comment: Check the page and it's masterpage (if any) for `asp:ToolkitScriptManager` element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove this ScriptManager and it will work fine.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

You have definitely added a ScriptManager somewhere else in your Page or MasterPage.

[ScriptManager Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx)

> Only one instance of the ScriptManager control can be added to the
>   page. The page can include the control directly, or indirectly inside
>   a nested component such as a user control, content page for a master
>   page, or nested master page. If a page already contains a
>   ScriptManager control, but a nested or parent component needs
>   additional features of the ScriptManager control, the component can
>   include a ScriptManagerProxy control. For example, the
>   ScriptManagerProxy control enables you to add scripts and services
>   that are specific to nested components.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your Masterpage has a Scriptmanager too?
Check your whole aspx page hierarchy...